# Prove there are no rational numbers a, b, such that $\sqrt 3 = a + b \sqrt 2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove it by contradiction, and say that $a + b \sqrt 2$ is rational, But I'm not sure how to tie in the $\sqrt 3$

Comment: Square both sides, you will get $3 = a^2 + 2b^2 + 2ab\sqrt 2$. Now apply rational/irrational logic

Comment: $\sqrt 3=a+b\sqrt 2$ implies $3=a^2+2ab\sqrt 2+2b^2$ implies $\sqrt 2$ is rational, absurde.

Comment: @Ataulfo why does it imply that sqrt(2) is rational?

Comment: It is see at first sight because you have $\sqrt 2$ as a quotient of rational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that were possible then we would have $(a+b\sqrt{2})^2)=a^2+2b^2+2ab\sqrt{2}=3$, this would imply $2ab\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb Q$. So we would have $ab=0$.

So you are left with two cases:

$a=0,b=0$.

The first case gives us $a^2=3$ which is clearly imposible in the rationals. The second one gives us $2b^2=3$, this is impossible. Let $b=\frac{p}{q}$ a reduced fraction. Then we have $2p^2=3q^2$ and so $3$ divides $p$. But then $p=3r$ and we have $2(3r)^2=3q^2\implies 2r3=q^2$ and so $q$ is also a multiple of $3$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You're halfway on the right track. But you're not going to be able to prove it's rational.

Suppose that you DO have $\sqrt{3} = a + b \sqrt{2}$. Try squaring both sides  and simplifying. Then do something like that again, until you've got no square roots. And then argue ( by looking at factors of 2 and 3 in $a^2, b^2, ab$, and other such numbers) that the resulting equation can't have rational solutions.

Reread the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational for inspiration.

When you've done all that, report back and maybe we can help you out some more.

Comment: There may not be any need to square again.